# Ruby Class instance method def initialize: instance or class method?

Tags: ruby

Let's take a normal ruby class:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end
end

bob = Person.new("bob")
```

My question is the nature of initialize. Here's the thing, `new` is clearly a class method, but seems to me that `initialize` is an instance method(not class) that is called on the instance created WHEN the class method `new` is called.

Do I have this right? Or can someone shed some new light? I've done some google searches and couldn't find any clarity.

Comment: it's kind of unique - you can access instance method scope from it but as you say it is callable like a class method. Note that initialize won't be called if you define `def self.new`.

Comment: does that mean its called as a result of the `new` method being called? or it is in fact the `new` method?

Comment: Yes. Note also that [Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is also a class method that creates two instance methods (here `name` and `name=`).

Comment: @maxpleaner: there's nothing unique about it. In fact, you can express `new`'s semantics in 3 lines of very simple Ruby code: `obj = allocate; obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block); return obj` The only "unique" method here is `allocate`, whose semantics cannot be expressed in Ruby: it allocates an empty object from the object memory and sets its class pointer to `self` – neither of those things can be explained from within Ruby. But even so, it is still a normal method, which can be overridden and overwritten like any other method … it just cannot be written in Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a new object is initialized (that is, when you call `new` on a class) what effectively gets called is this method:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

In the standard Ruby implementation, this method is implemented in C but is [well documented](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new).

To understand what's happening here you must be aware that in Ruby, even classes are Objects (they are instances or the `Class` class). Thus, when calling `new` on your `Person` class, you are actually calling the `new` method on the instance of a `Class` object.

As you can see, the `Person` class (being an instance of `Class` itself) brings a method to allocate memory for the new instance named `bob`. After the memory is allocated, the `new` method calls `initialize` on the newly created instance.

Comment: In reality, `initialize` is `private` by default, so the middle line is *really* more like `obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)`, but the end result is the same. If you have ever used Objective-C, that should look familiar, because `Foo.alloc.init` is essentially how you create an object.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag. I fixed the code and learned a bit more about how method dispatching works in C-Ruby.